# Finding close colors of a given color

Tags: actionscript-3, path-finding

I´d like to know, how, through actionscript 3, to get an array of ARGB (hexadecimal) colors, that is close to a given color.

Example:

0xFF00FF00

A green.

How to get variations of green?

I´m trying to get some green colors of a bitmapdata.
I´ve tried to get it by making a loop getting the colors using getPixels32. 
The problem is, I think the bits colors of each position are different from the bits of the bitmap rendered.

It´s for a pathfinder. 
Each green bit sets a node in a map, as walkable.
So I need to know what are these colors to set it as walkable for the pathfinder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please restrict your question! You have a color of some pixel close to red, green or blue and need to know what color is it? IMO: it's better to use 2d array for your purposes rather then bitmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RGB space is terrible for interpreting whether colors are similar to one another.  A different color space that matches closer to human perception of color is HSV (hue saturation and value).  Here are the steps you should follow:

1. Convert your value from RGB space to HSV (http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html)
2. Modify the saturation and value to obtain different shades of the same green hue.
3. You can even modify the hue a little with a defined tolerance level you specify
4. Reconvert back to HSV to RGB

I believe technically..one color space is smaller than the other, meaning it is not always a 1:1 conversion - but it should serve your purpose.